# HTML Password input - Password revealed in the URL

Tags: html, url, input, passwords

Ok, so this is the problem. I have a password input form that looks like this:

```
<form class="form1" action="WEBSITE.HTML" onsubmit="return (this.pass.value==='1234')?true:false;">
    <div class="row uniform half collapse-at-2">
        <div class="8u">
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="password" placeholder="Input password"/>
        </div>
    <div class="4u">
        <input class="fit" type="submit" value="Go" onclick="if (document.getElementById('password').value == '1234');" />
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

It works great, the only problem is that when I submit the right password, it redirects me to the website, for example, google, with this URL: google.com?pass=1234. So it basically reveals the password when someone inputs it correctly. Is there any way to avoid this? Hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Your password is already revealed as this is the worst way to implement password authentication possible. Scrap it and read up on server-side coding. For everyone's sake.

Comment: I know, I encrypted the HTML. I know it's not safe but it's just a really simple website with only a few users in it. I just want the url not to reveal the input. No way to do that? @JohnConde

Comment: HTTPS and POST are your friends.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? I'm a cut and paste html guy, haha. @scunliffe

Comment: @JohnConde It's really not needed, my high school class has a website, and we have a password input that redirects to a cloud storage, I just didn't want my teachers or other classes to find out the password.

Comment: @Alejandro if you use GET as the method for a form (which is the default if not specified) then all the params/values are sent in the clear on the URL. If you use POST it submits but not "in the URL".  Using HTTPS allows you to send your info to the server over an encrypted connection thus hiding the details from anyone "watching/listening" over the wire.

Comment: if you change the request method to `POST` instead of the default `GET`, it wont be visible in url. HOWEVER, that does not mean it wouldn't be visible to anyone inspecting the information sent.

Comment: Gotcha @MSTannu. That's why I'm encrypting the code. I don't think anyone in our school will have as much time to inspect the HTML. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `method` attribute in your form:

```
<form method="post" class="form1" action="WEBSITE.HTML" onsubmit="return (this.pass.value==='1234')?true:false;">
```

And I think you don't need to use `===`, use simple `==` instead.

**UPDATE:**

if your site doesn't like some hidden post values, use redirect without sending any of values:

```
<form class="form1" onsubmit="validateForm(); return false;">
    <div class="row uniform half collapse-at-2">
        <div class="8u">
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="password" placeholder="Input password"/>
        </div>
    <div class="4u">
        <input class="fit" type="submit" value="Go" />
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
    var pass = document.getElementById('password').value;
    if(pass == '1234') //here 1234 is your password
        window.location = 'https://www.google.com';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you! Love this community!

Comment: @Alejandro - Doing a POST request is surely the way to go, but checking the password on client side does not make sense at all, everybody can have a look at the password in the browser then.